# Android inline errors - editText height change

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an editText field with inline errors. However, whenever the error and error icon display, the editText field's height changes to accommodate the icon. Is there a way have the height remain unchanged?

There are no errors in the code, I'm talking about invalid entries creating inline errors via editText's setError().

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        style="@style/Field"
        android:id="@+id/first_name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/first_name_hint" />
```

Comment: Post the XML file and the errors you are getting.